# Docker-compose volumes sharing issue with /app folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to build a web application based on flask and vue.js, using docker containers.
I use volume sharing in docker-compose and I'm facing an issue with the container structure.
I'd like to share the application folder from the host with the /app container folder. To do so the docker-compose is set up as

```
volumes:
 - type: bind
   source: ./
   target: /app
```

inspecting the container shows that the data from the host is placed inside the folder /app/app and not inside the folder /app as expected. The working directory is set up inside the docker container:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest
WORKDIR /app

COPY dependency.yml .
RUN conda env create -f dependency.yml
COPY setup.py .
RUN pip install -e .
```

In an attempt to try to understand the relative/absolute path I tried to change the target volume to /data in the docker-compose file. In this case the application files are installed in the /app and the host files are copied in the /data folder, as expected.

The **question** is: why if I try to use the absolute /app folder in the container does the system use it as relative to the WORKDIR, and this happens only if the WORKDIR has the same name as the target folder?